# syntax error in C with eeprom function in AVR

Tags: c, syntax, avr

I have the following function. I have written it long time ago and used it well, but now it gives me a syntax error in Codevision software....
the error is in the declaration of the function and might be from the arguments....

```
void ReadGainPots(void);
void RxGetChannels(void);
void read_adc(uint8_t channel);
void output_motor_ppm(void);
void Initial_EEPROM_Config_Load(void);
void Save_Config_to_EEPROM(void);
void Set_EEPROM_Default_Config(void);
void eeprom_write_byte_changed( uint8_t * addr, uint8_t value );
void eeprom_write_block_changes( const char * src, void * dest, size_t size );

void eeprom_write_block_changes( const uint8_t * src, void * dest, size_t size )
{ 
size_t len;

for(len=0;len<size;len++)
{
    eeprom_write_byte_changed( dest,  *src );

    src++;
    dest++;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post the actual error?

Comment: Error: D:\Amin\Anjoman\quadcopter\project\main project\main\LUQuad.c(180): declaration syntax error

Comment: which is line 180 in the snippet above?

Comment: that's the first line, in fact line 180 is the prototype of the function

Comment: Show us the ten or so lines immediately _before_ that one.

Comment: Any reason why you have declared `src` to be `const uint8_t*` but `dest` as a `void *`? C99 says "A pointer to `void` shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type."

Comment: void ReadGainPots(void);
    void RxGetChannels(void);
    void read_adc(uint8_t channel);

void output_motor_ppm(void);

void Initial_EEPROM_Config_Load(void);
    void Save_Config_to_EEPROM(void);
    void Set_EEPROM_Default_Config(void);

    void eeprom_write_byte_changed( uint8_t *  addr, uint8_t value     );
void eeprom_write_block_changes( const char * src, void * dest, size_t size );

Comment: changed the void to char and still getting the same error

Comment: Prefix `const` to `uint8_t value` in `eeprom_write_byte_changed` because content of `src` is `const uint8_t` and you are passing to a non-const parameter in `eeprom_write_byte_changed`. Also make `dest` to be `uint8_t*`. Another option you can try is, compile the program using `avr-gcc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, without the error itself, it's a little hard to diagnose :-)

The *first* thing I would be looking at is whether the "Codevision software" understands the `uint8_t` data type. This type was introduced in C99 and it wouldn't surprise me if some embedded development environments still used C90.

It *could* be a simple matter of including the `stdint.h` header. Or, if the compiler *doesn't* support it, you can use another, compatible data type (possibly `unsigned char`).

An easy way to test this is to temporarily change `uint8_t` to `char` and see if the error goes away (or possibly, moves elsewhere). If it does, then you need to figure out which is the best way to go based on whether `uint8_t` is valid for your implementation.

If you're *certain* it's supported, then show us the actual full error being generated. Without that, we're rather hamstrung.

---

A few more things to check.

First, it's possible that the text immediately *before* that declaration may be causing a problem with it. It should be checked as well.

Second (and this is likely in an environment where you mix UNIX/Windows), check the line endings. I've seen issues with Windows-based CR/LF line endings in environments where the compiler expects UNIX-based LF endings.

Comment out the function and see if the error persists elsewhere (such as in the following function). That will give a valuable clue as to the cause (in the function itself, or some environmental problem).

---

For what it's worth, that code itself is quite valid. The following program compiles okay:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void eeprom_write_byte_changed (void *dest, uint8_t ch ) {}

void eeprom_write_block_changes( const uint8_t * src, void * dest, size_t size )
{
size_t len;

for(len=0;len<size;len++)
{
    eeprom_write_byte_changed( dest,  *src );

    src++;
    dest++;
}
}

int main(void) {
    eeprom_write_block_changes ("hello", NULL, 42);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the error is: Error: D:\Amin\Anjoman\quadcopter\project\main project\main\LUQuad.c(180): declaration syntax error

Comment: @AminSajedi, if that's the _complete_ error, you need to consider a better compiler. Even the most brain-dead ones I've seen give a better indication of what _part_ of the declaration is bad.

Comment: @Amin, you should probably change both the prototype _and_ the function.

Answer (score 1):

Either change `uint8_t` to `unsigned char`

Or, try including `stdint.h`

or `#define` `uint8_t` yourself.

Comment: The AVR toolchain supports C99, there's no nees for hacks like this.